# Form handling OOP PHP

Tags: php, forms, oop

I have a question about form handling with OO programming,

The way I am doing it now is:

-> html form (action=action.php?a=login)

the action.php file:

```
switch ( $_GET['a'] ) { 

 case 'login': 
    login stuff;
    break;
}
```

but I don't like it this way( it looks ugly, and its far from OOP ) and I think theres a better way, I dont know how.

I want to ask how can I do this on a good way. Btw I use MVC

Comment: You should start with grouping your utility code into functions before venturing into OOP and or yesteryears MVC buzzword.

Comment: I have a login function in my User class, its not that I place the login code directly inside the action.php file the file looks like: 
 case 'login':
  $user->login($user, $pass);

Comment: this should really be an answer but is too short, go and look at codeigniter and that would be the way forward for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd either have to come up with a  MVC framework stack that uses OOP yourself, or use one of the many frameworks out there. The usual method is to map actions to controller methods.

So `/users/login` would look like

```
class UsersController {
   function login() {
      //do your login stuff here
   }
}
```

As an initial step, you could move your actions to separate files and start grouping them by how they are related rather than having all your methods inside `actions.php`.